# PostgreSQL: Transactions

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

I am writing a client in JAVA using JDBC. I want to execute a statement like so

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("BEGIN; Delete from Table id=1 Delete from table2 id=1 COMMIT;");
```

Obviously the above statemnt will not work. So can I proceede as follows? Instead I am using Insert in this example.

```
con.setAutoComitt(false); 

String qry1 = "..." 
pst1 = con.prepareStatement(qry1) 
//Insert code here to add values to prepared statement pst1 
pst1.executequery(); 

String qry2 = "..." 
pst2 = con.prepareStatement(qry2) 
//Insert code here to add values to prepared statement pst2 
pst2.executequery(); 

con.comitt();
```

Would this be correct? Any help or docs would be great. I could not find anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much how you do it.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html  Might be a good idea to turn autocommit back on afterwards, just so you don't break something later.

Comment: So once I commit then the query statements get executed?

Comment: Nope.  The queries get executed, and then when you commit, they are committed.  You might want to look up how transactions work in the database docs.

Comment: If you want to execute a single statement and then commit, then you can just leave autocommit enabled: the commit is done automatically after a statement ends (eg for `DELETE` immediately, for `SELECT` after reading the result set). Only when you need a transaction over multiple statements (or if you want to use multiple statement simultaneously from a single connection) do you need to disable autocommit.

Comment: You are confusing batches and transactions. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly do the same when i want to communicate with my postgreSQL database

```
stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select osm_id from vertices;");
```

you have to execute every command in different "statement" cause each statement returns results for one query only if the statement contains more than one command it will throw an exception

Comment: @EliMiller No: the JDBC standard doesn't allow it. One `java.sql.Statement` execute should be one SQL statement (although some drivers have options to enable a more lenient mode that allows multiple statements).